# What can I do with a read-only Feature Service that I cannot do with a Map Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-platform

If I have a feature service with the editing capabilities disabled what can I do with it that I cannot accomplish with a regular Map Service?

I can't think of a purpose for having a Feature Service except for editing.  Even if I was building a JS API application and I wanted the geometries I could create Feature Layer object using a MapService URL which would query the service to get the geometries.  On top of that with the MapService I have the option of just using a regular dynamic layer in which case I get only the image back.

I also tried using the read-only feature service as input to a geoprocessing tool and that doesn't work either.

The regular Map Service seems to be a lot more flexible than the Feature Service for everything other than editing.

Comment: Try using it as an input to a Geoprocessing tool like Select or Buffer.

Comment: See also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78590/what-are-differences-between-feature-and-image-services-from-arcgis-online